# CRM 2016 Get Email by RegardingObjectId.Name not working

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, dynamics-crm-2013

I created a console application to pull information from "Dynamics CRM 2016". I'm using `XrmServiceContext` to fetch data, and I'm able to pull information from different entities, but I have problems when fetching `EmailSet` by a specific property.

my code:

```
//This works
var test= context.EmailSet.FirstOrDefault(e => e.RegardingObjectId.Id == Guid);
//This doesn't work
var test= context.EmailSet.FirstOrDefault(e => e.RegardingObjectId.Name == "somename");
```

this line is throwing an exception:

```
"Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method."
```

**Question:** Is it possible to query `EmailSet` by `RegardingObjectId.Name`?

I don't see anything special about this property hopefully someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Linq To CRM has some shortcomings, you can however use fetchxml which is a bit more flexible.

```
var results = service.RetrieveMultiple(
                    new FetchExpression(
                        string.Format("<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>" +
                        "<entity name='email'>" +
                        "<attribute name='subject' />" +
                        "<filter type='and'>" +
                        "<condition attribute='regardingobjectidname' operator='eq' value='{0}' />" +
                        " </filter>" +
                        "</entity>" +
                        "</fetch>", "foobar")));

var emails = results == null
    ? new List<Email>()
    : results.Entities.Cast<Email>();
```

Comment: +1 for giving a alternative solution to the problem, I prefer the simplicity of Linq to CRM when it works